# keep getting bad usage while trying to perform a partitioning and Formatting a Disk Drive in Linux

Tags: linux, fdisk

```
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier:  6C5A63BF-EF32-9244-8273-250775DB79D6

Device      Start     End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1 8704000 18874476 10170477 4.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb2   20480   53247   32768  16M ChromeOS kernel
/dev/sdb3 4509696 8703999 4194304   2G ChromeOS root fs
/dev/sdb4   53248   86015   32768  16M ChromeOS kernel
/dev/sdb5  315392 4509695 4194304   2G ChromeOS root fs
/dev/sdb6   16448   16448       1 5128 ChromeOS kernel
/dev/sdb7    16449   16449       1 5128 ChromeOS root fs
/dev/sdb8   86016  118783   32768  16M Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb9    16450   16450       1 5128 ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb10   16451   16451       1 5128 ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdbll     64   16447   16384   8M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb12 249856  315391   65536  32M EFI System

Partition 7 does not start on physical sector boundary. Partition 9 does not start on physical 
sector boundary. Partition 10 does not start on physical sector boundary. Partition table entries 
are not in disk order. student@d2e8a553c052:-$
student@d2e8a553c052:-$ student@d2e8a553c052:-$
student@d2e8a553c052:-$ sudo fdisk /dev/[SECOND DRIVE ] fdisk: bad usage
Try 'fdisk --help' for more information.
student@d2e8a553c052:-$ sudo fdisk --help

Usage:
fdisk [options] <disk>     change partition table fdisk [options] -1 [<disk>] list partition 
table(s)

Display or manipulate a disk partition table.


Options:
-b, --sector-size <size>
-B, --protect-boot
```

physical and logical sector size
don't erase bootbits when creating a new label

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do?  And what on what disk? /dev/sdb seems to be used.  Are you sure that this is the disk you want to operate on?     Also, can you format the cut and paste inside a code block so that newlines are preserved?

Answer (score 1):

In general you would start with

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

or

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

You can find the device node (the sd* part) by looking in /dev with

```
ls -al /dev/ | more
```

Look for lines starting with a 'b' (for 'block device').

Good luck.